# How do I mock ApolloMutation component?

Tags: testing, graphql, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

Everything about the app works fine except the testing.

I have tried to use `mount` and `shallowMount` methods exposed by `@vue/test-utils` to mock the `ApolloMutation` component.

I have seen couple of solutions on `VueApollo` testing. I have tried [this](https://dev.to/n_tepluhina/testing-vue-apollo-components-with-jest-3gj3). In my case, I'm using `NuxtApollo` community module. I tried to apply it the same way,  but throwing error about the wrapper been empty, not sure if importing the `@nuxtjs/apollo` is the right thing to do.

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import VueApollo from '@nuxtjs/apollo'
import Register from '../pages/register/index.vue'

describe('Register user', () => {

  let localVue
  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(VueApollo, {})
  })

  it('Should click the register button to register', () => {

    const mutate = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Register, {
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $apollo: {
          mutate,
        }
      }
    });

    wrapper.find('.callMe').trigger('click')
    expect(2+2).toBe(4)
  });
});
```

The component I want to test.

```
<template>
  <ApolloMutation
      :mutation="require('../../apollo/mutations/createUser.gql')"
      :variables="{firstName, lastName, username, phone, email, password}"
      @done="onDone">
    <template v-slot="{ mutate, loading, error }">
      <input v-model="firstName" placeholder="first name">
      <input v-model="lastName" placeholder="last name">
      <input v-model="username" placeholder="username">
      <input v-model="phone" placeholder="phone">
      <input v-model="email" placeholder="email">
      <input v-model="password" placeholder="password">
      <button :disabled="loading" @click="mutate">CreateUser</button>
      <button class="callMe" @click="callMe">CreateUser</button>
      <p v-if="error">An error occurred: {{ error }}</p>
      <p v-if="loading">loading...</p>
    </template>
  </ApolloMutation>
</template>
```

I expected the output to be `4` but I got the error: `[vue-test-utils]: find did not return .callMe, cannot call trigger() on empty Wrapper`

Answer (score 1):

Should be `import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'` not `import VueApollo from '@nuxtjs/apollo'`.

Replace that everything should be fine.